# Does PowerShell support negation syntax in glob pattern?

Tags: powershell, glob

In Linux, Bash supports [negation syntax in glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Unix) like `[!abc]` for one character other than `a`, `b`, and `c`.

I'm trying to find something similar in PowerShell.

In [Supporting Wildcard Characters in Cmdlet Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is no description related to negation. Also, when `test.txt` exists, I confirmed the following, which indicates that `!` is not supported as negation syntax like Bash.

- `ls tes[!s].txt` returns nothing.
- `ls tes[!t].txt` returns `test.txt`

Does PowerShell support negation syntax in glob pattern? If not, could you share some alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not (as you correctly deduced from such a feature not being documented, nor working).

An alternative are regular expressions, but you'd have to do the filtering yourself, then:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object Name -match '^tes[^t]\.txt$'
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem 'tes?.txt' | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike 'tes[qrs].txt' }` would be another option.

Comment: Agreed; filter as much as possible on left-hand side.

Comment: To explain a little more what Ansgar and Bill are saying, by having `Get-ChildItem` filter it tells the provider to filter it's results before sending them to PowerShell. The provider is very efficient at it's job (after all, it's only got one job), including filtering results, so it is much faster at doing so than PowerShell is. Always filter at the provider level where possible.

Comment: @Joey That's not entirely true. Starting in v2 PowerShell will hand off any filtering it can to the provider, if the provider accepts partial filtering (like the FileSystem provider does). Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.containercmdletprovider.convertpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Provider_ContainerCmdletProvider_ConvertPath_System_String_System_String_System_String__System_String__) for more info on that.

Comment: Oh, nice. Good to know and I can finally stop using `-Filter` all the time :)